# insert np.nan into dictionary elements using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, list-comprehension

I would like to know how to replace elements of a dictionary that don't meet a condition. For example, I want to replace all elements of the dictionary that don't equal 2 with nan:

```
test = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2,3,4,5]}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
test2 = {name: item if item == 2 else np.nan for name in test.keys() for item in test[name]}
```

I would like the following answer:

```
test2 = {'a': [nan, 2, nan, nan], 'b': [2, nan, nan, nan]}
```

Instead, I am getting:

```
test2 = {'a': nan, 'b': nan}
```

If I do it via list comprehension instead, e.g.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a2 = [item if item == 2 else np.nan for item in a]
a2 = [nan, 2, nan, nan]
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nesting the loops, but you're not specifying that one should target the list. They're both adding the same keys to the same dictionary, constantly overriding themselves. To fix it, do the following:

```py
test2 = {name: [item if item == 2 else np.nan for item in test[name]]
         for name in test.keys()}
```

Note how the first for loop populates the dictionary, and the second one takes care of the contents of the list.